# Should I check isset($_GET[...]) when I expect it to always be set?

Tags: php, get, isset

I was recently placed on a project with some PHP, and I don't know much about PHP. There are a couple instances in the site where upon clicking a button, the user is redirected to another page with some URL parameters. The next page then uses `$_GET` to get those parameters and move on.

Another issue in the code caused the page to reload the second page without the parameters, so using `$_GET` would return errors, but with the other issue fixed, I can't think of a reason why the parameters wouldn't be there.

While debugging, I came across advice to always check `$_GET` using `isset()`, but theoretically there should never be an instance when those parameters aren't there (otherwise something else is really wrong with the server or the code).

Is it still worth putting in the checks and working out a backup solution, even though there shouldn't be a need for it? I want to make sure I'm not ignoring some other potential issue that I may not be aware of.

Comment: It's not that hard to manipulate the URL and remove the get parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always good practice+recommended to check your variables before applying any logic.

`!empty()` is recommended to use instead of `isset()` because it check both that variable is initialized and have some values too.

In case of array `count($array)>0` can be used as a check.

***Why to use `!empty()` check here:-*** [!empty() Vs isset()](http://www.geekgumbo.com/2010/12/18/php-the-difference-between-isset-and-empty/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting or requiring data to be sent via $_GET you should check if it's set. Especially since that data can be easily manipulated. Also like @Alive to Die said `!empty()` is better.

> isset() checks if a variable has a value including ( False , 0 , or
>   empty string) , but not NULL. Returns TRUE if var exists; FALSE
>   otherwise. On the other hand the empty() function checks if the
>   variable has an empty value empty string , 0, NULL ,or False.